# GAE display index.html with JAX-RS

Tags: google-app-engine, jersey, jax-rs

I'm pretty sure this questions is very easy.
I built a app with google app engine. I use JPA and JAX-RS with Jersey.
my web.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?><web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.5" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
         <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>services</param-name>
   <param-value/>
  </init-param>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

My index.html is in war/WEB-INF/index.html. What do i need to do to display it ?

Comment: i guess just running the project in eclipse will open the browser and show the file as it is also in the Welcomelist. Else you can navigate to server root and append /resources as specified in the URL-pattern

Comment: when i navigate to http://localhost:8888/resources comes 404 error,
but the methods from jax_rs are working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

index.html should go directly under war as in war/index.html.

Comment: i put it under war/index.html and could reach under localhost:8888

Answer (score 0):

keep your file in war folder itself, 
Don't keep inside WEB-INF.

Once you have taken it out,
You just need to give localhost:8888/  it will display the welcome-file ie index.html

you can keep other Jsp's inside WEB-INF, it will just be invisible for direct URL access.